# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SecIdentity"

Tags: swift, undefined-symbol

Xcode won't let me compile this code:

```
func getIdentity(keychainArray: NSArray) -> SecIdentity? {
    let dict = keychainArray[0] as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
    let key = kSecImportItemIdentity.takeRetainedValue()
    return dict[key] as SecIdentity?
}
```

The compiler quits with following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SecIdentity", referenced from:
 __TFC9messenger10Connection19streamOpenCompletedfS0_FT_T_ in Connection.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tested a few thing and have seen that SecIdentity is a type alias. 
I found out that the compiler always generates these error messages when i try to cast something to a type alias. If i cast it to a class (eg. NSObject / NSDictionary) it does work, but CFDictionary would also lead to a error. Does that help?

Comment: Are you linking against `Security.framework`?

Comment: Yes, see comment bellow

Answer (score 1):

[SecIdentity and friends](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000157) are part of the Security Framework, so it sound like you need to link against that.

Comment: I guess you mean "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" in the Targets General Tab. I have already tried to add the Security framework. No success. Do i have to link them somewhere else as well?

Comment: @user3211074 No, that *should* do it.

Comment: No success. I am using Xcode 6 Beta iOS 8.0 and OS X 10.10.