# How do I use CFArrayRef in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift

I'm using an Objective-C class in my Swift project via a bridging header. The method signature looks something like this:

```
- (CFArrayRef)someMethod:(someType)someParameter;
```

I started by getting an instance of the class, calling the method, and storing the value:

```
var myInstance = MyClassWithThatMethod();
var cfArr = myInstance.someMethod(someValue);
```

Then try to get a value in the array:

```
var valueInArrayThatIWant = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(cfArr, 0);
```

However I get the error `Unmanaged<CFArray>' is not identical to 'CFArray'`. What does `Unmanaged<CFArray>` even mean?

I looked through [How to convert CFArray to Swift Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684750/how-to-convert-cfarray-to-swift-array) but I don't need to convert the array to a swift array (however that would be nice). I just need to be able to get values from the array.

I have also tried the method of passing the `CFArray` into a function outlined [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24111307/2446155):

```
func doSomeStuffOnArray(myArray: NSArray) {

}
```

However I get a similar error when using it:

```
doSomeStuffOnArray(cfArr); // Unmanaged<CFArray>' is not identical to 'NSArray'
```

I am using `CFArray` because I need to store an array of `CGPathRef`, which cannot be stored in `NSArray`.

So how am I supposed to use `CFArray` in Swift?

Comment: Casting a `CGPathRef` to `id` helps in Objective-C, not sure about Swift though.

Comment: Could you use a `UIBezierPath` which can contain a `CGPath`, is conforms to `NSCoding` so you should be able to put it in an `NSArray`.

Comment: @Zaph I considered that, but that seems to make it more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: @duci9y The CGPath's are created and added to the `CFArray` in the Objective-C file, so it might work, as well as what Zaph said. However I am looking for a way to use `CFArrayRef` in Swift.

Comment: Why are you intent on using a `CFArrayRef` when the obvious solution is to use native arrays? Any particular reason?

Comment: @duci9y I was trying to avoid the conversion from `CGPath` and another class like `UIBezierPath` (and back). It sounds like that step is necessary.

Comment: You just need to put a cast to `id`, that's all. And even if you go the `UIBezierPath` way, it is a much, much shorter way than trying to get `CFArrayRef` to work nicely with Swift.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained in
[Working with Core Foundation Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective_c_apis/working_with_core_foundation_types), there are two possible solutions when
you return a Core Foundation object from your own function that is imported in Swift:

- Annotate the function with `CF_RETURNS_RETAINED` or `CF_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED`.
  In your case:

  ```
  - (CFArrayRef)someMethod:(someType)someParameter CF_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED;
  ```
- Or convert the unmanaged object to a memory managed object with `takeUnretainedValue()` or `takeRetainedValue()` in Swift. In your case:

  ```
  var cfArr = myInstance.someMethod(someValue).takeUnretainedValue()
  ```

Comment: This is a great find, and it fixed the issue at hand. However, the value returned from my `CFArrayGetValueAtIndex` call is of type `ConstUnsafePointer<()>`. Any idea how I might cast that to `CGPathRef`? I guess I've run into [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684750/how-to-convert-cfarray-to-swift-array)

Comment: @SantaClaus: I tried a bit but could not find a solution to extract the CGPathRef from the array in Swift. You are probably better off with using NSArray containing UIBezierPath objects.

Comment: Yep. I converted my Objective-C code to return an `NSArray` of `UIBezierPath` objects just a bit ago. Its a shame I can't make `CFArray` work though.

Comment: @MartinR Do I need to manually call `release` after a `takeRetainedValue` (I'm calling [`UTTypeCreateAllIdentifiersForTag(_:_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1447261-uttypecreateallidentifiersfortag))? If not, how does Swift manage this memory?

Comment: @Alexander: No, you don't. After the takeRetainedValue the object is treated by ARC like any other reference type, and a release is sent to the object when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @MartinR Ohhh, I see. Do you know of any resources that give more details on the exact workings of these core foundation types in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

An `Unmanaged` is a wrapper for an actual CF value. (Sort of like an optional.) It's there because ARC can't tell from looking at the declaration of `someMethod:` whether that method retains the value it returns.

You unwrap an `Unmanaged` by telling ARC what memory management policy to use for the value inside. If `someMethod` calls `CFRetain` on its return value:

```
let cfArr = myInstance.someMethod(someValue).takeRetainedValue()
```

If it doesn't:

```
let cfArr = myInstance.someMethod(someValue).takeUnretainedValue()
```

After you do that, `cfArr` is a `CFArray`, so you can use the bridging tricks from the other questions you linked to for accessing it like a Swift array.

If you own the code for `someMethod` you can change it a bit to not need this. There's a couple of options for that:

- Annotate with `CF_RETURNS_RETAINED` or `CF_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED` to tell the compiler what memory behavior is needed
- Since it's an ObjC method, bridge to `NSArray` and return that--it'll automatically become an `[AnyObject]` array in Swift.

Comment: Would bridging it to `NSArray` have any adverse side effects since the `CFArray` contains `CGPathRef`s which cannot be contained in an `NSArray`?